# Facebook Public Data Scraping

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape public data from facebook using python by implementing the following functionalities:

1. Search using a keyword and scrape data
2. Scrape a profile
3. Scrape a page
4. Scrape a post

I tried using the `graph api` but it kept giving me `authorization error`.

I kept looking around and as it seems, one needs to have proper permission from facebook in order to scrape data off facebook using automated means.

Can anyone tell if it's really possible to scrape data for the above screnarios. 
And if yes, how?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: where is your code? if you get error then show it in question. You only waste time.

Answer (score 1):

- **Search using a keyword and scrape data:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/ ("Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.")
- **Scrape a profile:** Only possible if the user of the specific profile authorizes your app with the `user_posts` permission, no matter if public or not
- **Scrape a page:** If you manage the Page, use a Page Token. If not, apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)
- **Scrape a post:** Depends on who made the post. If it is a user: see "Scrape a profile". If it is a Page: See "Scrape a page".